# Delete elements from iframe Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a built-in iframe from a pools app webservice.
To add the iframe of a pool I add this code:

```
<script>
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = (('https:' == d.location.protocol) ? 'https://' : 'http://'),
        r = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000000);
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async=1;
    js.src = p + "www.opinionstage.com/assets/loader.js?" + r;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'os-widget-jssdk'));
</script>
<div id="18993" class="os_widget" data-path="...." data-comments="false" data-of="..."></div>
```

The structure of the html when the iframe loaded is:

```
<div id="18993" class="os_widget" style="..." ... >
    <div class="os_widget_container os_widget_container0" style="..." >  
        <iframe " name="os_frame" style="..." src="... "> (no id)    
            <!DOCTYPE html>
                    ...
                    <body>
                         ...
                         <h1> </h1>
                         ...
                    </body>
             </html>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide or delete h1.

I have tried these with no success, even It doesn't allow me to add a id to iframe and of course I can't delete or hide h1:

a)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var iFr = $('iframe');
iFr.load(function() {
    iFr.attr('id','something');
    iFr.contents().find('h1').css({'display' : 'none'});
    //iFr.contents().find('h1').remove();
    //$('something').contents().find('h1').hide();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

b)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var f = $("iframe");
f.load(function(){
    f.find(' h1').css({'display' : 'none'});
    //f.find('h1').hide();
    //f.contents().find('h1').remove();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Any help, would be great and appreciated
Best
Jose

Comment: You cannot access elements inside an iFrame which gets its content from a different URL/ domain

Comment: Thanks @empiric There is no exception, right?

Comment: [This](http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls) ressource might help you. But in general, when you don't have full access the the iFrames source/domain this is restricted due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security reasons you cannot access the content of an iFrame with its source coming form another domain, called the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

There are some excpetions which are explained [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls).

The most reliable way to access html inside an iframe is, when you have access to the iframes source and/or domain.

A dirty way around that would be scraping the html from the other side and include it under your domain, but I definitely would not recommend doing this.
You lose a lot of functionality and maybe miss crucial updates.